# Access Rails.env variable in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to access `Rails.env` somehow directly through javascript/jQuery?

I could put something in the DOM and then read it, but that seems a bit hackish.  Specifically, I'd like to be able to make a conditional statement in the javascript based on whether the environment is testing, development, staging, or production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is possible without reading from the DOM; the solution for me was to insert the environment variable into the js file before precompilation.

Change `myfile.js.coffee` to `myfile.js.coffee.erb` and then insert with Ruby same as in a view, etc:

```
environment = "<%= Rails.env %>"
```

Answer (score 5):

Rails is on the server. jQuery is on the client. You must *somehow* supply the information from the server to the client. The typical way is outputting a bit of JavaScript using server-side code, like so:

```
<script>
var environment = "<%= Rails.env %>";
</script>
```

...assuming the value won't have double quotes in it. Rails presumably has an equivalent to PHP's `json_encode` you could use if necessary.

Comment: That was my understanding as well, was hoping maybe there was another way. Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: ["Rails presumably has an equivalent to PHP's json_encode you could use if necessary."](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript)

Comment: @MikeCampbell: *Similar*, not quite the same (rather more limited in scope). But would do the job here!